# Running proxy server through localhost

Tags: windows, proxy, ip, localhost, configure

I've been looking everywhere but I can't seem to figure out how to configure localhost and a proxy ip.

Basically I have localhost at 127.0.0.1, and I mapped it to myserver.local.  I want to be able to run my test application on localhost (myserver.local) when connected via a proxy ip address in chrome.

I'm running windows.  Thanks!  Any help would be appreciated!